# Writing clear proofs involving multiple theorems and conditions

Tags: proof-writing

Suppose the problem is that given $A$ and $C$ holds, prove $D$ holds.

Some theorems that we can use are:

> $A \to B$
>
> $(B,C) \to D$

I feel what I said may be unclear:

> Because $A$ holds and $A$ implies $B$, $B$ holds. Because $B$ and $C$
>   holds and $B$ and $C$ imply $D$, $D$ holds.

Usually $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ are long sentences and may contain "and" again.

Also there sometimes can be more conditions and theorems for proving $D$.

In all of these cases,
the above quote can be very long and I am afraid may be confusing.

How would you write it?

Do you mainly use words or  formulas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're concerned about long complex statements, you should give names for statements just like you've done in your post. For some real-life examples:

- [Property A](http://www.ams.org/notices/200804/tx080400474p.pdf)
- [Property T](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazhdan's_property_(T))
- [Theorems A and B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan's_theorems_A_and_B)

Better yet, make an adjective describing when conditions hold; e.g. given an integer $n$,

- if (long statement $A$) is true of $n$, it is called a "wiggly number"
- if (long statement $B$) is true of $n$, it is called a "porcupine number"
- etc.

and then phrase your argument like

> Because $n$ is wiggly, Lemma 3 implies it is also porcupine. Because $n$ is both porcupine and applesauce, Lemma 5 allows us to conclude that $n$ is fuschia.

Comment: Property B seems worth mentioning here, too: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_B

Comment: +1 If a property appears as prominently as in your example in several theroems, it is certainly worth a definition to allow a shortcut name that may even be useful outsider your specific proof. There are so many theorems about natural numbers with exactly two divisors that it is a necessity to coin a name for these numbers.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to be liberal in the use of the word “then”. When you write “If A, B, C”, it’s not clear whether the conclusion is B and C, or whether the hypothesis is A and B. If you mean “If A, then B and C”, write that; if you mean “If A and B, then C”, write just that. I try (and I’ll bet I don’t always succeed) to preface the conclusion with the word “then” in every case.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that it depends on who your audience is and how formal you want your proof to be. I usually assume that my audience is aware of how Modus Ponens works. So I would organize it as follows.

---

Given that:

> \begin{align}
> A &\implies B \tag 1 \\
> B \land C &\implies D \tag 2
> \end{align}

we want to prove that:

> $$A \land C \implies D$$

To this end, suppose that $A \land C$ holds so that $A$ holds and $C$ holds. Then since $A$ holds, it follows by $(1)$ that $B$ holds. But since $C$ holds, we know that $B \land C$ holds. Hence, by $(2)$, we conclude that $D$ holds, as desired. $~~\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is clear to me.

You can readily turn this
into "proofical" form
by changing

A holds and A implies B, B holds. Because B and C holds and B and C imply D, D holds

into

1. $ (A \land (A \implies B)) \implies B$
2. $((B \land C) \land ((B \land C) \implies D)) \implies D
   $

Therefore

3. $\left(A \land C \land (A \implies B)
   \land ((B \land C) \land ((B \land C) \implies D)\right) \implies D
   $

Answer (score 1):

Since you say that you have certain theorems available, I assume that they have some name ("Theorem 42" or "Smith's foobar-lemma") that yuo can refer to. This should allow to avoid lengthy repetitions.

We have that (lengthy property $A$ holds). By thoerem1, this implies that (lengthy property B holds). Together with (lengthy property $C$), this allows us to conclude from theorem 2 that (lengthy property $D$).

To summarize, a proof (outside certain specifically formal requirements) should not only be formally correct, but also *readable* by the audience. Writing full sentences with interjected formulas is very helpful for the reader, even  for the mathematical reader who is well acquainted with $\forall$, $\land$ and $\Rightarrow$. In fact, many submissions to exercsies that consist only of a dozen lines of equations are *not* readable in this sense, because the intention of the author is not conveyed: Only too often, people forget the connectives between the lines (is it $\Rightarrow$ or $\Leftrightarrow$? Often it shold be $\Leftarrow$!) that are *necessary* for following the argument, and when correctly inserted would make gaps in the argument apparent (also to the author).